# 「のれん代」(Goodwill) and 「のれん」 of 居酒屋

Tags: usage, words, kanji, etymology

Is there any relation between 「のれん代」(Goodwill) and 「のれん」 of 居酒屋?

And how about those kanji, are they using same kanji for both?

If there are the same kanji, I would like to know their etymology, like how のれん代 is formed from のれん.

Comment: 暖簾 (noren) and 暖簾代 (norendai).

Comment: のれん are not only at entrances of 居酒屋. Almost every store used to have a のれん.

Answer (score 4):

(Not sure why nobody answered this) Yes, from [here](http://gogen-allguide.com/no/noren.html):

> 元々、暖簾は禅宗の用語で寒さを防ぐためにかけられた垂れ布をいい、簾の隙間を覆い暖めることから名付けられたもので、現在と同様の意味で用いられるようになったのは近世以降のことである
>   屋号などを記して店先にかけられることから、のれんは店の信用なども意味するようになり、「暖簾分け（のれんわけ）」や「暖簾代（のれんだい）」という語も生まれた。

**Translation**

[暖簾]{のれん} originally is from Zen buddhism and refers to a cloth which was hung and used to protect from the cold. It was named after the fact that it was used to cover the openings of [[簾]{すだれ}](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%99%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8C) to help keep warm (暖). The meaning used nowadays originally started in the early modern period (Edo or later). 
Also, since Noren have the shop name on them and are hung in the front of shops, Noren have also become to mean the "trust" or "credibility" of a shop and words like 暖簾分け（のれんわけ）and 暖簾代（のれんだい）were produced as a result.